# como puedo hacer que se valide un select box?

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en una macro para reprogramar citas, y en una parte me encuentro con un `SelectBox` que funciona de la siquiente manera:

Cuando se selecciona una fecha, el `SelectBox` se llena con las horas disponibles, y al seleccionar una hora, se valida y permite el acceso a la otra parte del formulario, es decir, el `ccs` de la segunda parte cambia y los `selectBox` que hay allí se habilitan.

Esto solo pasa cuando hago `click`, pero al momento de usar la `macro` y reemplazar el **value** del `SelectBox`  con una de las opciones, no se valida y no activa el resto del formulario.

Me pude saltar esto y activar el formulario *por la fuerza*, pero los siguientes `selectBox` no muestran la informacion necesaria.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para *enviar* la información que necesita para que se valide el formulario y habilite la siguiente parte?

```
var primeraHora = document.querySelector("#appointments_consulate_appointment_time > option:nth-child(2)").value; 

document.querySelector("#appointments_consulate_appointment_time").value = primeraHora;
```

Esta es la parte del código, con el que cambio el valor del `select`

Comment: `var primeraHora = document.querySelector("#appointments_consulate_appointment_time > option:nth-child(2)").value;
document.querySelector("#appointments_consulate_appointment_time").value = primeraHora;`

esta es la parte del codigo con el que cambio el valor del select

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Zerok, ¿que tal? Bienvenido. Si no querés que te baneen la pregunta, deberías reformularla. El código que pusiste en los comentarios agregalo en la pregunta.
Y quizás esté mal tagueado también. ¿A que te referís puntualmente cuando hablás de macros en javascript? ¿Estás usando sweet.js? Podés agregar más tags si querés.

Comment: Mi consejo es que si tenés un select, pongas el html también. Toda la información que sea relevante para que te puedan ayudar. Saludos.